# multi select apperance is different in IE8 and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

PFA screen shot of IE8 and chrome.

In IE8, multi select drop down does not have disabled scroll bar while in chrome, disabled scroll can be seen at the side of multi select drop down.

> ***My requirement***: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAqtE.png) To show disabled scroll bar when content is less than size of multi select. 
>   [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z59lO.png) When content increases more than size then scroll bar should appear automatically.

Please suggest how to achieve the same.

[image: Chrome Multi Select]

[image: IE8 Multi Select]